# PHP Magic Constants

Tags: constants, php

I am trying to get the filename of the script that is running (But not the include it is calling).

```
echo basename(__FILE__); # will always output include.php

echo basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
# This will do what I want (echo myscript.php), but I was wondering if there was
# a better way to grab it, as I have had problems with $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']
# when running certain scripts from a cron.
```

Any suggestions?

```
<?
#myscript.php
require('include.php');
echo "Hello all";
?>

<?
#include.php
echo basename(__FILE__);
echo basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use **$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']**, as explained in the [reserved_variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) man page

'**SCRIPT_NAME**'
    Contains the current script's path. This is useful for pages which need to point to themselves. The `__FILE__` constant contains the full path and filename of the current (i.e. included) file.

Comment: Just to let you know, for what ever reason, an older server I was using the $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] and possibly $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] was returning nothing when run via the cron. But I take your point about using SCRIPT_NAME over SCRIPT_FILENAME. So thanks

Comment: $_SERVER["argv"][0] may have what you want also.

Comment: argv[0] is the script name as it is invoked by the cmd line, so the path included is absolute, relative ( path/name.php, ./path/name.php, etc) depending on __how__ you invoke the script. Moreover it could be undefined when not in cli environment

Answer (score 1):

If you're using something `php -f /home/me/foo.php in your crontab (i.e. [php-cli](http://docs.php.net/cli)) you might also be interested in the [$argv](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) array. $argv[0] contains the path/name of the script initially passed to php.

Comment: Thanks that will be helpful! Not thought of using that for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I did some test on what you have and dont have and there it is a sollution that worked fine for me ;)
The file from which the code is name Debug.php and bellow is the method responding for the name of the log file.

Both in browser and in cron the result in my case is: **test.log**

```
public static function filename($value = null) {
        static $_filename;
        if (isset($value)) $_filename = $value;
        if ($_filename === null) {
            $_filename = '';
            if (strlen($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"])) {
                $filename = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"];
            } else if (count($_SERVER["argv"])) { // for cron calls
                $filename = $_SERVER["argv"][0];
            }
            if (!strlen($filename)) {
                $filename = __FILE__;
            }
            $arr = explode('.', basename($filename));
            $_filename = array_shift($arr) . '.' . Debug::extension();
        }
        return $_filename;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember using '`$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]`' but have no idea if it has problem with corn.

Answer (score 0):

When PHP is executed from the command line (likely how you have cron set up) **SCRIPT_FILENAME** will contain *the path specified by the user*. If your script is executed as `../myscript.php` then that is the value you will get. Seeing as you are passing the value through `basename()` anyway, it should still suit your needs. What problems were you having with it exactly?

**SCRIPT_NAME** is another predefined variable to look at, but this will not always contain the *absolute* path to the executed file either.

Comment: Not really sure why it was happening or how, we have moved servers since then and everything working as expected now. Just wanted to check that the $_SERVER variable was the one I should be using.